# PGAdmin4 with SSH port forwarding using identity file asks for file password

Tags: ssh

I am using PGAdmin 4, the application, on Ubuntu 20.04.1 (Zorin 16). I am using an SSH tunnel and an identity file. This works. However every time I connect, I am prompted for a password for the identity file. The file is not password protected, other than filemode of 600. There does not seem to be any issue with not supplying the password, but is it supposed to be the password of the remote SSH login, or the password of my current user for "su" purposes? Or is it just a glitch?

Inspecting the properties, the buttons (and these are of  a fat pair radio buttons in lieu of a checkbox) are not persistently remembering my choice to use a private key.

Comment: Have the same issue and cannot find a fix

Comment: This has been killing me for the past day and a half. More annoyingly, this was working last week, can figure out what changed that killed this. The Identity file password field never came up until I tried to opened a session yesterday.

Comment: I'm also having exactly the same issue. Dose anyone got any answer for it yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pdAdmin config probably has ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD set to False. Check under Help / About.

What helped me:

Go to the install folder of your pgAdmin client, look for file config.py in a subfolder /web and edit it. Change
ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD = True

Now, when asked for the password of the ident file, enter any dummy password (if your ident file is not password protected) and tick the save checkbox. You should now never be asked again.

Comment: Amazing. To me tunnel password means SSH password not SSH-key encryption password, maybe they leverage this option and use it for either since they are mutually exclusive? I do have to do it for every server using the same SSH key which is painful only the first time.  For me this file was /usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py.

Answer (score 2):

It is a red herring. Ignore the request for the password key file. Just click OK to bypass it without entering anything.

Then you just enter your database password as you normally would have.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, just provided my database master password it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug/issue/feature in PGAdmin that has been raised and closed because they didn't work out a fix (I have suggested an easy fix): https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6032